# Threejs draw diiferent lines

Tags: javascript, three.js, drawing, lines

We use `three.js` to draw some maps. On a map there are should be some lines (like some borders, isolines). So we know how to draw just dashed lines. But also I want to draw lines with such type of patterns. So what would be better way to do that? Texturing?

[image]

UPD:
Map is gonna be 3D (but the lines are not), you can rotate it and zoom it etc.
It uses WebGl renderer.

Comment: Leaves lots of questions ... how are the "maps" going to be used, are you going to zoom in close, is it going to be 2d or 3d? CanvasRenderer or WebGLRenderer?

Comment: Still not very clear what you intend to achieve exactly, though it sounds like you have really only one viable option. You draw on a canvas and use that as a texture, might be a bit expensive on GPU memory, but you'll have no real difficultly drawing thicker lines or certain patterns like in your question.

Comment: @Leeft I want to achieve something like this lines with trianlges on the weathermaps
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BUyq3EDfyIE/T6Gez5LJ6yI/AAAAAAAABpY/3pivoGsj19A/s1600/Weather+map+1200.JPG

Comment: Definitely sounds like drawing to a canvas and using that as a texture is the way to go.

Comment: @Leeft thanks! But could you please write is like an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing you exactly what needs to be done to achieve all this would cover several tutorials by itself, so I'm going to link you to some.

You could start here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element ... that'll give you a basic page and a canvas to start drawing on, and various instructions on how to draw some shapes (this is going to be the hardest part for you; it'll require many different draw calls for these various shapes and it'll probably be somewhat difficult to position them correctly on your map). I'd suggest you create functions to draw the various basic shapes you need, and you will need plenty of 2D math in these functions which are perhaps worthy of SO questions by themselves.

To make dashed lines like in your example picture, http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/html5-canvas-dashed-lines.html is useful. Anything more advanced than that you'll have to draw yourself though, combining various shapes on the canvas.

Also note you'll want to use a canvas size where the width and height are a power of two, so use something like 512x512 or 1024x1024 before you use it as a texture.

Once you have your canvas rendered the way you want it to, applying it to an object in a three.js scene is pretty easy:

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10 );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( plane );
```

You'll have to use a more advanced material if you're not copying the map you want to draw on to the canvas first as you can only apply limited textures to a single surface. But, get your 2D drawing sorted first as that is the hard part.